# Injection of Camel uri into jaxrs bean does not work anymore

Tags: apache-camel

I'm trying to migrate a "pure CDI" webapp from Camel 3.9.x on Wildfly 20 to Camel 3.11.x on Wildfly 22.

I have the following code:

```
@Produces
@ApplicationScoped
public final CamelContext createContext() {
    ...       
}


@Path("/demo")
public class MyJaxRsWebServices {

    @Inject
    @Uri("direct:...")
    private FluentProducerTemplate endpoint;
```

which is running fine in Camel 3.9.x + wildfly 20
but failed in Camel 3.11.x + Wildfly 22, with the error:

> WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "esb-v3-trv-1.0.0-rc.1.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit."esb-v3-trv-1.0.0-rc.1.war".WeldStartService" => "Failed to start service
> Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type FluentProducerTemplate with qualifiers @Uri
> at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject @Uri private net.****.MyJaxRsWebServices.endpoint
> ...
> "}}

As far as I understand:

- previously my Camel routes were started before Weld is trying to inject Camel beans (such as producer templates) into my JAXRS bean
- now  Weld seems to try to inject Camel beans **before** Camel is kicked in.

It's yet not clear to me whether such change is due to Wildfly internals, or to Camel it-self.

Questions:

1. Are there any recent changes (since Camel 3.9) in Camel CDI extension (`CdiCamelExtension`) which could explain the new boot order?
2. If not, is it possible to annotate

- either my route builder classes to start asap?
- or my web service bean to wait for Camel beans (using a kind of "@DependsOn" - which only stands for EJBs)?

Comment: Useless to add that when I comment the "@Inject" line, I do see that Camel routes are started...but after the JAXRS bean is mounted

Comment: When using Camel annotation "@EndpointInject" (instead of CDI equivalent @Inject @Uri) everything is working fine again !